# De Gruyter template: Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language ngerman yet

Tags: pdftex, babel, german

I'm writing an article (in English) that requires the De Gruyter journal article template (available [here](https://www.degruyter.com/dg/page/production-for-authors)).

Just trying to compile the file `journal-article.tex` in the package's zip file (link above), I get the following error:

```
! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language ngerman yet.
```

It objects to the command `\iflanguage{ngerman}{\def\Authand{ und }\def\Authands{ und }}{}`, line 2466 of `degruyter.sty`.

This problem with the De Gruyter template has been described [here](http://mbork.pl/2017-06-26_de_Gruyter_style_and_Package_babel_Error_You_haven't_defined_the_language_ngerman_yet), where the proposed solution is to install the package `hyphen-german`. However, I have no luck with this solution. I've confirmed that I already have this package (`tlmgr install: package already present: hyphen-german`) and yet the error remains.

I've also installed the package `german` and `babel-german`. I tried installing a package called `ngerman` but this package doesn't exist in my repository:

```
tlmgr: package repository http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr install: package ngerman not present in repository.
```

Are there any ways around this problem or some other german packages I'm supposed to install?

I'm using `pdflatex`, (`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)` on Mac OS 10.12.6 (Sierra).

Comment: The error means that the ngerman hyphenation patterns are not activated on your system. Run `kpsewhich language.dat`. Open this language.dat in your editor. Does it contain a line `ngerman loadhyph-de-1996.tex`?

Comment: Just checked `language.dat` as suggested. Indeed it does have a line `ngerman loadhyph-de-1996.tex`.

Comment: Then the pattern didn't find there way in the format. What do you get with `kpsewhich --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` and with `kpsewhich --all --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt`?

Comment: Both point to the same file, `~/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`

Comment: oh tinytex. well try `fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdflatex` and check if it is updated. If not check the documentation of tinytex for find out how to do it.

Comment: This command followed by `sudo mktexlsr` seems to have solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `hyphen-german` is the correct package required. Hopefully, for any future De Gruyter template users that encounter this issue, simply installing the `hyphen-german` package will be sufficient to solve the problem (as in the blog post linked in the original question).

In my case, I had installed `hyphen-german`. However, as discussed in the comments, it appears that a file in my TeX installation, `pdflatex.fmt`, was not being updated properly.

The solution that worked for me was to run the command `fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdflatex` followed by `sudo mktexlsr`. I still don't really understand why I had this trouble, but it seems to be resolved for now. It may be something to do with TinyTex.